# SAS Executing empty SQL commands in macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Ive a table with some SQL commands that i execute in a macro, but when they empty i get some syntax errors because its expected some value.
My table looks like this:

| libname | tablename | SQL MAX_DATE | SQL_SUM_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lib1 | table1 | select max(date) from lib1.table1 | select sum(ammount) from lib1.table1 |
| lib1 | table2 | select max(dt_a) from lib1.table2 |  |
| lib2 | table1 |  | select sum(cash) from lib2.table1 |

Now. i've a macro that run all records in this table and updates the result of the sql commands to other fields (sum_num, max_date), something like:

```
%macro exec_SQL;
proc sql;
  select libname, tablename, sql_max_date, sql_sum_num
  into :lib1-, :tab1-, :sql_dt1-, :sql_num1-
  from have
quit;
 
%do i=1 %to &sqlobs;
  proc sql;
    update have 
    set 
      max_date=(&&sql_dt&i.), 
      sum_num=(&&sql_num&i.)
    where libname="&&lib&i."
    and tablename="&&tab&i.";
  quit;
%end;
%mend exec_SQL

%exec_SQL
```

Any way to get around this? I tryed to use the case statment on my update, but didnt have any luck, getting also another errors of syntax :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor the first PROC SQL to get each update SQL separately, with the variable to be updated embedded in the macro variable.

```
%macro exec_SQL;
proc sql;
  select libname, tablename, upd
  into :lib1-, :tab1-, :upd1-
  from (
    select libname, tablename, cats('max_date=(',sql_max_date,')') as upd
    from have 
    where not missing(sql_max_date)
    union
    select libname, tablename, cats('sum_num=(',sql_sum_num,')') as upd
    from have 
    where not missing(sql_sum_num)
  );
quit;
 
%do i=1 %to &sqlobs;
  proc sql;
    update have 
    set &&UPD&I
    where libname="&&lib&i."
      and tablename="&&tab&i.";
  quit;
%end;
%mend exec_SQL;

%exec_SQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just fix the metadata.  Since those two target variables are NUMERIC just set the empty values to a period.  If the target variable was character then set it to a quoted space.  You could even do it in the query that is populating the macro variables.

```
select libname
     , tablename
     , coalesce(sql_max_date,'.')
     , coalesce(sql_sum_num,'.')
  into :lib1-
     , :tab1-
     , :sql_dt1-
     , :sql_num1-
  from have
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the macro variable is not empty and selectively run your SQL statements based on that.

```
%macro exec_SQL;
proc sql;
  select libname, tablename, sql_max_date, sql_sum_num
  into :lib1-, :tab1-, :sql_dt1-, :sql_num1-
  from have
quit;

%do i=1 %to &sqlobs;
  proc sql;
    update have 
    set 

      %if(%superq(sql_dt&i.) NE) %then %do;
        max_date=(&&sql_dt&i.)
      %end; 

      %if(%superq(sql_dt&i.) NE AND %superq(sql_num&i.) NE) %then %do;
        ,
      %end;

      %if(%superq(sql_num&i.) NE) %then %do;
        sum_num=(&&sql_num&i.)
      %end;

    where libname="&&lib&i."
    and tablename="&&tab&i.";
  quit;
%end;
%mend exec_SQL;

%exec_SQL
```

If you want a generic macro that tests if a macro variable is empty, you can use this:

```
%macro isnull(macvar);
    %if %symexist(&macvar.) %then %do;
        %sysevalf(%superq(%superq(macvar)) =, boolean)
    %end;
        %else 1
%mend isnull;
```

If the macro variable does not exist or if it is empty, it returns a 1. Otherwise it returns a 0. Pass the macro variable name directly without an `&`, similar to `%superq()`. e.g.:

```
macvar = foo;
%put %isnull(macvar);
```

Indirect references:

```
%macro test;
    %let citylist = Chicago Philadelphia NYC;
    
    %do n = 1 %to 3;
        %let city&n = %scan(&citylist, &n);
        %if(%isnull(city&n) = 0) %then %put *** The city is &&city&n...
    %end;
%mend;

%test;
```